# Azure Devops YAML Pipeline - Clean up dynamic deployments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Our current pipeline deploys a new instance of our app for every new branch created on azure repos, just like review apps on Heroku or Gitlab.
The creation part went smooth, but I'm not sure what to do with the orphaned resources and deployment once the branch is deleted (hopefully by an accepted pr).

Deleting them manually is not an option and there I can't find a trigger in the documentation for branch deletes.

The only option I can see right now is to create a scheduled job for the master branch(since it always exists) with a bash script that compares the list of deployed apps and existing branches and cleans up the resources.

Is it my only option, or is there another way without a fairly complex, all-access, destroy machine?

Comment: Do you want to delete the build pipeline corresponding to the deleted branch or  want to delete the resources deployed on the server?

Comment: The deployed resources, like the docker swarm stack, databases, azure queues, etc.

Comment: As far as I know, apart from manual deletion, you can only try to implement it through script.There should be no such trigger:once the branch is deleted , the relevant deployment resources are automatically deleted.

Comment: ya have same issue, would be really cool if i could trigger on approval of pull request, thus to clean up test resources! is there really no way to achieve this in yaml pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So did a little investigation dumping all enviroment vars to Notepad++ and using the compare plugin i realized that when a PR is accepted 2 env variables are different.

First of the initial variable "BUILD_REASON" during a push is set to "IndividualCI", but with the "BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH" set to "refs/heads/feature/******". When a pull request is initiated the "BUILD_REASON" changes to "pullrequest" and "BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH" to "refs/pull/***".

Finally when a PR is accepted the variables change to "BUILD_REASON" = "IndividualCI" and "BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH" = "refs/heads/master".

Once i figured out this i could create stage that have the following conditions:

```
- stage: CleanUp
  displayName: 'CleanUp'
  dependsOn: Test
  condition:  and(succeeded(), in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'),in(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'))
```

The above stage will be triggered when PR is accepted so to cleanup resources created during PR :-) havnt tested all the way but seems to do the job.

Comment: I assume with this you are having to manually check what orphaned resources are left that needs to be cleaned up? This is just only running this step on a master build?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a webhook in Azure DevOps to watch the pull request for updates. When the pull request status changes to completed, fire a script that deletes the resources used for the PR.